# I joist flange cut into

Tags: plumbing, joists

Is this cut into the flange OK or do I chase the builder to fix?

[image: Plumber messed up?]

Comment: Your image description suggests that the plumber messed up, but it's the _carpenter_  or builder who made the mistake. It's routine to look at toilet and other drain locations and set floor trusses around them. That said, the plumber certainly should've cleared this modification with the builder, but that takes responsibility back to the builder anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's okay, but a lot depends on the regulations in your area.

1. You should discuss it with your architect/engineer.
2. Or raise it with your builder and ask them to write a waiver (for the insurance) that it is ok and is a current building practice in your city.

Once you have spotted it, you need to do something about it and document it, otherwise, your insurance company has an excuse to not pay out in case of disasters.

Answer (score 3):

Cutting an I-beam is not OK. Most of the instruction sheets for these beams state not to cut or notch it. It could possibily be sistered with additional wood but redoing the plumbing would be a nightmare. I would get with the inspector and builder and have it corrected.